# I want to find entire content of a Cell Q5 in another cell Y. e.g Q5=Comapny Europe & Y= Company Europe, Company Spain

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to find entire content of a `Cell Q5` in another `cell Y`.

> e.g Q5=Comapny Europe & Y= Company Europe, Company Spain.

I used `"*"& Q5 &"*"` but as it finds company say yes

Comment: Then use find() to find the text "company" and if() to control yes or blank. Not sure what is in Q5 and not sure of the result you want. Edit to give a clear before and after.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Y:Y,"*"&Q5&"*")>0,"Yes","No")
```